# Edit a field that is visibility hidden

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to edit an input field with javascript while the field is visibility:hidden? It doesn't seem to be possible.

Comment: edit with javascript? please be more specific

Comment: or without jquery `document.getElementById('someId').value="Hu?"`;

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/VVgan/

Comment: You used `$('mydiv').val("blah blah")`? Aren't you missing a "#" to select the div by ID. If you just use "mydiv", it looks for all elements with the tag "mydiv", which is both invalid and probably won't exist. Using "#mydiv" will select the element with the id "mydiv".

Comment: If I understand `visibility` correctly, it stays in context within the html document. You should be able to dynamically change the content without showing changes. However, your changes might resize the `div` or `span` you want to change. Have you tried making changes using the `block: none` and then making the `block: display`?

Comment: @Shabab What is "block"?

Comment: Yes it is very possible.

Comment: @ianpgall Sorry about that. I mixed up the order. It should actually be `display: block`. Display is a style property which you can change around in CSS or with an inline `style` attribute.

Comment: @Shabab No problem. I know what it is, I wasn't sure if you were referring to something else or didn't know the syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It is possible to edit an input field with javascript while the field is "visibility:hidden".

Comment: and how is that, can you please elaborate your answer rather a comment.

Comment: Yes, it is my code that is emptying it. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

does not matter whether, it is visible. it accessible through javascript as an visible one is. if **rendered** on the page.

Comment: Good point - some people don't understand that using attributes on the server, such as "Visible" in ASP.NET don't actually render the control.

Comment: visibility: hidden is a CSS property. With javascript I can edit that field programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

Well as long as you now some identification to the element it will work.
For example `document.getElementById('lol').value = 'hello';`

Answer (score 0):

Element can be edited programmatically.
For example: http://jsfiddle.net/xTpRa/

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo is below:

```
if document.getElementById.style is visible    

then 

document.getElementById.val() == "new value"
```

Right??

Comment: What's `.val()`? Do you mean `.value()`?

Comment: sorry value() actually. I am used to jQuery so I said val()

Comment: It's not `value()`, it's `value`

Answer (score 0):

If by `visibility:hidden` you mean a CSS property then yes, it can be modified the same way you'd modify any other element.

```
document.getElementById('controlID').value = 'new value';
```

However, if you're talking about an ASP.NET control with the `Visible=False` property, this element would not even render on the page and would therefor not be editable.

Edit: According to your comment, you tried:

```
$('mydiv').val("blah blah");
```

The problem with this code is that you forgot your `#`, which specifies to the jQuery selector that you're looking for an element with the id `mydiv`. Without the `#`, it means you are looking for elements of type `<mydiv>`, which would not match anything. Try this instead:

```
$('#mydiv').val("blah blah");
```